# How to Pass a Value based on Record Id

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created a list view to display records here i am passing json value to record for storing my data temporary. so in component i have declared one string attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="comnt" type="string"/>
```

and passed this attribute as a value for button.

```
 <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
        <form>
            <ui:inputTextArea aura:id="RejectComments" label="Comments" rows="5" value="{!v.comnt}"/>   
        </form>
     </div>
```

this `comnt` value is coming from my controller.

```
 var flow = component.find("flowIDFbulk");        
    var inputVariables = {
        "Reject":[]            
        /*
        {name : "IC_Review_Action_RB",type : "String",value :"Reject"},
        {name : "IDFrecordID",type : "String",value :component.get("v.rejIDFValue")},
        {name : "Rejection_Comments",type : "String",value :component.find("RejectComments").get("v.value")}
    ]*/
    };
        var obj = {};
        obj["name"] = 'IC_Review_Action_RB';
        obj["value"] = 'Reject';
        obj["RecordId"] = component.get("v.rejIDFValue");
        obj["Comments"] = component.find("RejectComments").get("v.value");
        inputVariables.Reject.push(obj);
        alert(inputVariables);
         alert(inputVariables.Reject[0].RecordId);
         for(var i = 0; i < inputVariables.Reject.length; i++)
         {
               if(inputVariables.Reject[i].RecordId == component.get("v.rejIDFValue"))
               {
                   //alert(inputVariables.Reject[0].Comments);
                   var comnt = inputVariables.Reject[i].Comments;
                   //alert(comnt);
                   //component.find("RejectComments").set("v.value", comnt);
                   //component.get("v.RejectComments")
               }
         }

    //alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
    //flow.startFlow("Bulk_Decision_Disclosure_Review", inputVariables);
    component.set("v.isRejectOpen", false);
```

Now i am able to store value temporary. but for every record it's showing same value.
how to pass Value to `ui:inputTextArea` based on `recordId`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle lists you need to utilise `<aura:iteration>`and a `List` type attribute.
I'd suggest following below pseudo code and restructure your code.

```
<aura:attribute type="List" name="listOfObjects"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.listOfObjects))}">
  <aura:iteration value="{!v.listOfObjects}" var="obj">
    <ui:inputTextArea label="Comments" rows="5" value="{!obj.comments}"/> 
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:if>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{! c.handleSave }" />
```

And In controller

```
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        //Initialise listOfObjects
   },

 handleSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        //get listOfObjects and save
    },
```

Comment: thanks @Ranga for your effort. but in my case..i have used <aura:iteration> for iterating of records. now the controller line which i have post is an Modal Popup screen Field.here i want to check recordId and pass my comments value.

Comment: Yes, if you use the same attribute to store the value of the comment per row, value will be same for all the records. That's why I suggested you iterate through the list and set the value per record.